# Fetch weirdness in JavaScript with for...in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to request JSON data from two different URLs using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and format it with JSX before loading it into the state object. It's only retrieving the data from one of the URLs.

I have the URLs in an object like this:

```
var urls = {
  'recent': 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent',
  'alltime': 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime',
};
```

I want to fetch the data by iterating over the object containing the URLs, turn it into an array of JSX objects, then store the result in my main object's state.

```
for (var key in urls) {
  var url = urls[key];
  fetch(url).then((response) => {
    response.json().then((json) => {
      var userNumber = 0;
      var html = json.map((user) => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{++userNumber}</td>
            <td>
              <img src={user.img} alt={user.username} />
              {user.username}
            </td>
            <td>{user.recent}</td>
            <td>{user.alltime}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      }); // Close json.map block.
      this.setState({
        'data': { [key]: html }
      });
      console.log(key);
    }); // Close response.json block.
  }); // Close fetch block.
}
```

It should fetch the data from the `recent` URL and store the formatted result in `this.state.data.recent`. Then it should do the same thing for `alltime`, storing the result in `this.state.data.alltime`. What it actually seems to do is fetch `alltime` twice.

This makes no sense to me at all. I don't even have a guess as to what is happening.

I have noticed that if I put log statements into fetch's arrow function it shows that it's hitting both keys and both URLs, but if I put log statements at the end of the `response.json()` arrow function, after `json.map`, it shows `alltime` twice.

It's processing the second URL twice. I know that the order isn't guaranteed, but it does tend to process them in the order in which I defined them and I think that's significant here. Even if it is a problem with asynchronous requests happening at the same time, though, they're two different requests ultimately storing data in two different places, aren't they?

A version of this code is also [at CodePen](http://codepen.io/VAggrippino/pen/PWGqQe), but I'm likely to change that as I try to figure out what's going on here.

Full code:

```js
var urls = {
  'recent': 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent',
  'alltime': 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime',
};

function View(props) {
  return (
    <form className="view">
      <label>View: </label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="view" value="recent" checked={props.view == 'recent'} />Past 30 Days</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="view" value="alltime" checked={props.view == 'alltime'} />All Time</label>
    </form>
  );
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      'view': 'recent',
      'data': {
        'recent': null,
        'alltime': null,
      },
    };
  }
  
  componentWillMount() {
    for (var key in urls) {
      var url = urls[key];
      console.log(key);
      console.log(url);
      fetch(url).then((response) => {
        response.json().then((json) => {
          var userNumber = 0;
          var html = json.map((user) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{++userNumber}</td>
                <td>
                  <img src={user.img} alt={user.username} />
                  {user.username}
                </td>
                <td>{user.recent}</td>
                <td>{user.alltime}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          }); // Close json.map block.
          
          console.log('Setting state for ' + key);
          this.setState({
            'data': { [key]: html }
          });
        }); // Close response.json block.
      }); // Close fetch block.
    }
    /*
    fetch(urls.recent).then((response) => {
      response.json().then((json) => {
        var view = 'recent';
        var html = json.map((user) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src={user.img} alt={user.username} />
                {user.username}
              </td>
              <td>{user.recent}</td>
              <td>{user.alltime}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        }); // Close json.map block.
        this.setState({
          'data': { [view]: html },
        });
      }); // Close response.json block.
    }); // Close fetch block.
    */
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <View view={this.state.view} />
        <table>
          {this.state.data[this.state.view]}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
img {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<main id="app"></main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async functions and for loops are one of the big topics in js (may search them on SO) . They can be solved using  an IIFE or let:

```
for(let key in keys){
  //your code, key will be locally scoped
}
```

or:

```
for(key in keys){
(function(key){
   //key is locally scoped
 })(key);
 }
```

What happens? Youve got just one key, so it will just have one value at a time, the for loop will finish before the async functions execute:

```
key="recent";
key="alltime";
//async functions run
```

Why does local ( block) scoping helps? Well:

```
 {
 key="recent";
 //async function one fires, key is recent
 }
 {
 key="alltime";
 //async function two fires, key is alltime
 }
```

Comment: I had a feeling this had something to do with the asynchronous functions not completing before the next iteration of the loop. I actually tried both `let` and `const` on `url`, `html`, and even `userNumber`. I completely forgot about `key`. Clearly my understanding of working with asynchronous functions is a little week. Thank you!